# iOS 8 UITableViewController separator scrolling render

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, scroll, render

I've come accros a problem with iOS 8 on the iPhone6 and simulator, when you have a UITableViewController with visible separators there seems to be some render problem. Now I could post some code but really if you make just a simple UITableViewController you would have the same problem, just look at eBay and Kijiji they all have this issue.

Normally you wouldn't see this small difference if it only happened once in a blue moon but if you scroll none stop you will see it flash. (less on Ebay since their separators are too close to white but Kijiji is pretty apparent)

Sorry I wanted to post a screenshot but sadly I don't yet have the reputation to do so therefore you will have to try it out yourself's.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Many times it's less about scrolling non-stop though it's more about scrolling very gently and looking at the grey separators only. I don't have an iPhone 6 Plus but I have a iPhone 6 and I can also reproduce it on a iOS 8 simulator (which I know can have some render glitches but it can be done on a phone too). Also if you scrolling really gently and stop when the separators grow in size and stay at that position while removing your finger the separator will stay bigger than the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `Renders with edge antialiasing` in your `plist` file, fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why the separators flash is because the app is not designed for the larger displays, and the phone is upscaling the app to fill the larger screen.  Since the separator height becomes fractional, the separator line crosses pixel boundaries and becomes antialiased, making it appear wider, lighter, and/or darker than normal.

The answer is to (wait for the developer to) update the app to support the native resolutions of the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

You can enable native resolution in your own app by adding launch images or a launch screen file.

- Launch images

  - **iPhone 6** requires a portrait launch image of 750x1334.
  - **iPhone 6 Plus** requires both portrait (1242 x 2208) and landscape (2208 x 1242) launch images, since it can launch apps in landscape as well as portrait.
- Launch screen file (iOS 8)

  You can add a launch screen storyboard or nib through Xcode.

  - In Xcode 6, open the `File` menu and choose `New` > `File...` > `iOS` > `User Interface` > `Launch Screen`.
  - In the `General` tab for your project's settings, look for the `App Icons and Launch Images` section.  Set the `Launch Screen File` to the name of the file you created.  This will set the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key in your Info plist.

Comment: I have launch images in my project both for Retina 5.5 and Retina 4.7 but still facing that issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Clips Subviews on my custom cell did fix the issue for me.